# How to loop array and add to the end

Tags: php, arrays

After hours of trying to figure this out I'm hoping I can come to you guys for help! What I want to do is for each deck (declared by `$filename`) I want to create an array that holds all of the cards in that deck (there are 15 cards in each deck). Then compare a member's collecting deck with the full set of cards and then compare my trading deck with their "still need" array. The array/code works great... if I wanted to only compare one deck.

I can't figure out how to keep the values from the loop and add more onto the array instead of overwriting it. I'd love to have a list of ALL cards that the member needs from across ALL decks, not just one deck.

I've tried version of `array_push`, `array_merge`, but I'm at a loss. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

```
$select3=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `cards` ORDER BY `filename` ASC");
while($row3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select3)) {
    // pulls all cards from database
    $filename=$row3['filename'];
    $deckname=$row3['deckname'];
    $cardcount=$row3['count'];
    $count=substr_count($collecting, $filename);

    $expcol=explode(", ", $collecting, -1); //puts member collecting deck into array
    $exptra=explode(", ", $trading, -1); //puts my trading deck into array

    if($count>0) {
        $cardarray=array($filename."01", $filename."02", $filename."03", $filename."04", $filename."05", $filename."06", $filename."07", $filename."08", $filename."09", $filename."10", $filename."11", $filename."12", $filename."13", $filename."14", $filename."15",); // creates array of all cards in specific card deck


        $stillneed=array_diff($cardarray,$expcol); //shows cards other member still needs from the deck
        $res=array_intersect($stillneed, $exptra); //shows cards I have that the other member still needs
        $countres=count($res); // counts how many cards I have that other member needs

        if($countres>0) {
            $check="✓"; // if I have a card to give, create checkmark
        } else {
            $check="";
        }
    }
}
```

To be more specific, let's assume I only have two rows in my database

newdeck

testdeck

I want to create an array that includes newdeck01, newdeck02, newdeck03, testdeck01, testdeck02, testdeck03. When I use the code above any time it grabs testdeck, it erases all the newdeck items in the array. Only one deck works at a time, but I want to list ALL the decks at the same time in the same array. I hope that makes sense.

### EDIT

I think I did it!! Here is my updated code.

```
$select3=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `cards` ORDER BY `filename` ASC");
$cardarray=array();
while($row3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select3)) {
    // pulls all cards from database
    $filename=$row3['filename'];
    $deckname=$row3['deckname'];
    $cardcount=$row3['count'];
    $count=substr_count($collecting, $filename);

    $expcol=explode(", ", $collecting, -1); //puts member collecting deck into array
    $exptra=explode(", ", $trading, -1); //puts my trading deck into array

    if($count>0) {
        for($i=1;$i<=$cardcount;$i++) {
            if($i<10){
                $in="0".$i;
            } else {
                $in=$i;
            }
            $items=$filename.$in;
            $cardarray[] = $items; // creates array of all cards in specific card deck
        }
    }
}   

$stillneed=array_diff($cardarray,$expcol); //shows cards other member still needs from the deck
$res=array_intersect($stillneed, $exptra); //shows cards I have that the other member still needs
$countres=count($res); // counts how many cards I have that other member needs

if($countres>0){
    $check="✓"; // if I have a card to give, create checkmark
} else {
    $check="";
}
```

Comment: As a side note, the rows in the card database are JUST the deck, not each individual card, so it'd be something like |newdeck|15cards|category1|etc...

Answer (score 0):

> you can merge two arrays In php if you want all cards in same array.

```
`$a = array('a', 'b');
$b = array('c', 'd');
$merge = array_merge($a, $b);`
```

Comment: Yeah, but how do I do that through the loop?

Comment: Show me your code you done with loop and be specific what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I posted the code in the original post - It's being put through a while loop.

Comment: send me link of that post.